# Output precision of long over double

Tags: c#

I'd want to display `-922337203685477.5808` on the console screen but I can't no matter how much I've tried. This is my program,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:F4} - {1:F4}", long.MinValue/10000.0, long.MaxValue/10000.0 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing integer division as `long.MinValue` is, by definition, a long.

If you want to force something with more precision then cast your values to something like a `decimal`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F4} - {1:F4}", ((decimal)long.MinValue)/10000.0M, ((decimal)long.MaxValue)/10000.0M );
```

You can simplify this also by just ensuring the `10000` is a decimal:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", long.MinValue / 10000M, long.MaxValue / 10000M);
```

Comment: @Jamiec There is no need to cast explicitly, `Console.WriteLine("{0:F4} - {1:F4}", long.MinValue / 10000.0M, long.MaxValue / 10000.0M);` will work as well. It will work even without specifying formats and `.0` - `Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", long.MinValue / 10000M, long.MaxValue / 10000M);`.

Comment: @SᴇM well spotted.

Comment: @Grim double can store only up to about 15.955 significant digits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format, so `long.MaxValue` converted to `double` loses some precision `9223372036854780000`

Comment: I understand that - hence the comment that I felt like an idiot - thanks for explaining it and providing links though!